# coding form data to email Excel file in ASP

Tags: asp.net, excel

is it possible to take the form data generated on an ASP file, put that into an excel file created on the fly and then email that Excel file to email address(es) and not just store it on the server?  Also, if it makes it easier, and I don't know if this is possible, but in researching this issue today I see you can have HTML pages with necessary ASP code embedded in it, could I do that here to achieve my customer's desired result?  their entire website is in .asp so not sure if I could make this page something else (i.e. PHP, Perl, Java etc.) if it'll be easier/possible in another language.  Much appreciate any help, I am a level 1 programmer I would say and got a customer who's site is all in ASP and I have never worked with this language, so I am getting a little lost rather quickly

Comment: if Excel attachment is not possible the file can be CSV, they just have an Excel file that stores this data so they would love to get their order data in Excel and then just copy and paste that data into their master order log, so a CSV file would work as well

Answer (score 0):

Just about everything is *possible*, just not necessarily *easy*...

You might consider using [OpenXML for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx) or some third-party tools (e.g. [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/total-component.aspx).Cells, which I use myself) to generate the Excel workbook, then attach it to an email.  I use Aspose.Email to send mails, but there are free solutions to that too.